# Python C-Extension segfaults when accessing through tp_getset

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, python-c-api

I'm trying to write a C-Extension for python. What I'd like to write is a ModPolynomial class which represents a polynomial on (Z/nZ)[x]/x^r-1[even though you may answer to my question without knowing anything of such polynomials].

I've written some code, which seems to work. Basically I just store three PyObject* in my ModPoly structure. Now I'd like to add the storage for the coefficients of the polynomial.

Since I want the coefficients to be read-only, I'd like to add a getter/setter pair of functions through PyGetSetDef. But when I access the getter from python(e.g print pol.coefficients) I receive a Segmentation Fault.

The original code, without the "coefficients" can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8xqavgBw).
The code with the coefficients is [here](http://pastebin.com/8zwS5wHD).

I hope someone of you can tell me where I'm doing wrong here.
By the way, also comments on the code are welcome. This is my first extension and I know that I'm probably doing things quite badly.

As ecatmur says in the comments PyVarObject store a certain number of "slots" at the end of the struct. So I've decided to avoid them.

The relevant code is:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    /* Type specific fields */

    Py_ssize_t ob_size;
    PyObject **ob_item;
    Py_ssize_t allocated;

    PyObject *r_modulus;
    PyObject *n_modulus;
    PyObject *degree;
} ModPoly;



static PyObject *
ModPoly_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    ModPoly *self;

    self = (ModPoly *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self != NULL) {
        [...]

        self->ob_size = 0;
        self->ob_item = NULL;
        self->allocated = 0;
    }

    return (PyObject *)self;
}


static int
ModPoly_init(ModPoly *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    PyObject *r_modulus=NULL, *n_modulus=NULL, *coefs=NULL, *tmp;
    PyObject **tmp_ar;

    static char *kwlist[] = {"r_modulus", "n_modulus", "coefficients", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "OO|O", kwlist,
                                     &r_modulus, &n_modulus, &coefs))
        return -1;

    [...]

    // The polynomial defaults to "x", so the coefficients should be [0, 1].
    tmp_ar = (PyObject **)malloc(2 * sizeof(PyObject*));
    if (tmp_ar == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(self->r_modulus);
        Py_DECREF(self->n_modulus);
        Py_DECREF(self->degree);
        return -1;
    }

    tmp_ar[0] = PyInt_FromLong(0);
    if (tmp_ar[0] != NULL) {
        tmp_ar[1] = PyInt_FromLong(1);
    }

    if (tmp_ar[0] == NULL || tmp_ar[0] == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(self->r_modulus);
        Py_DECREF(self->n_modulus);
        Py_DECREF(self->degree);
        Py_XDECREF(tmp_ar[0]);
        Py_XDECREF(tmp_ar[1]);
        free(tmp_ar);
        return -1;
    }

    self->ob_size = 2;
    self->allocated = 2;

    return 0;
}

[...]

static PyObject *
ModPoly_getcoefs(ModPoly *self, void *closure)
{
    printf("here"); // "here" is never printed
    PyTupleObject *res=(PyTupleObject*)PyTuple_New(self->ob_size);
    Py_ssize_t i;
    PyObject *tmp;

    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (i=0; i < self->ob_size; i++) {
        tmp = self->ob_item[i];
        Py_INCREF(tmp);
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(res, i, tmp);
    }
    return (PyObject *)res;
}

static PyObject *
ModPoly_setcoefs(ModPoly *self, PyObject *value, void* closure)
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AttributeError,
                    "Cannot set the coefficients of a polynomial.");
    return NULL;
}

[...]

static PyGetSetDef ModPoly_getsetters[] = {
  {"coefficients",
      (getter)ModPoly_getcoefs, (setter)ModPoly_setcoefs,
    "The polynomial coefficients.", NULL},
  {NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL}  
};


static PyTypeObject ModPolyType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
        0,                                                                      /* ob_size        */
    [...]
    ModPoly_members,                                        /* tp_members */
    ModPoly_getsetters,                                     /* tp_getset */
    0,                                                      /* tp_base */
    [...]
};

[...]
```

**edit**

I tried to reimplement the getter instruction by instruction, and I understood what I wasn't doing. In the ModPoly_init function I create the tmp_ar where I store the coefficients, but I do not assign it to self->ob_item.

-facepalm-

Comment: *The ob_size field of the header is not used; its presence in the type structure is a historical artifact that is maintained for binary compatibility with extension modules compiled for older versions of Python. Always set this field to zero.* http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics

Comment: Please post your code inline in your question (with any unnecessary code removed).

Comment: Oh, I'd forgotten that note. But does this mean that PyVarObjects are obsolete? Reading the source of python2.7.3 I can see that it is still used at least by the list type. What is the difference between the VAR and the normal HEAD macro?

Comment: Var objects end with a declaration of an array with 1 element, but are allocated enough memory for `n` elements off the end of the object.  You almost certainly don't need to use them.

Comment: If you know Python and C you could write a C extension using [Cython](http://cython.org). It is much nicer and more portable between Python versions.

Comment: I know Cython but I'd really like to write the extension manually.
I want to learn how python works behind the scenes, and I think being able to write an extension in C is a first step in this direction.

Comment: You could generate annotated C source e.g., [cython -a modpoly.pyx](https://gist.github.com/166dbd0c5e2a4d1a8d50). It is not very exciting to write INCREF/DECREF by hand.

Comment: I didn't know the -a option, thank you Sebastian.
Anyway I found out what I was missing. Really I've already started to hate writing C extensions(actually I think in C generally)...
(I've edited the questions to make it a bit less messy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only seem to be assigning to `ModPoly.ob_item` in `ModPoly_new()` (setting it to `NULL`).

`ModPoly_getcoefs()` then dereferences the null pointer, which would give you your segfault.  It looks like you intended to assign to `ob_item` in `ModPoly_init()`, but don't actually get around to doing so.